# How do I stop using Winzip and let Windows handle .zip files natively?

Tags: zip, winzip

Anytime I download a `.zip` file or create a compressed folder, my PC makes it a Winzip file, which is no good because I don't want to pay their fee to get the full version (the version I have was a trial one I obtained when I had this one .zip file that needed it to work).

Basically, I just be able to have regular `.zip` files without them being Winzip.

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking for a different compression utility, I recommend [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) on Windows - it's free, and does more than Winzip.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall WinZip by going into "Programs and Features" (Vista / Windows 7) or "Add/Remove Programs" (XP). Unintalling WinZip should cause Windows to revert to it's native ZIP handling behavior. If the Windows ZIP handler doesn't meet your requirements, you can always install something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you need WinZip for some specialist features, but want to use the inbuilt facilities in most case, just (for w8):
- go to Control Panel
- choose Programs
- choose 'Make file types always open in a  specific program'
- scroll down for ".zip"
- select 'change program' in the top right
- choose 'windows explorer'

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a .zip file and select open with 
And then other applications

Select the app you want and check the box that says always use "app" for opening .zip files

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10: remove all winzip or any other zip programs through control panel, programs, etc.
right-click on start button, settings, apps, default apps, choose default apps by file type, scroll down to .zip file type, click on it then click on "windows" as thw default app for opening .zip files